# Error in chisq.test for only some rows in R

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a sample dataframe as shown below:

```
CNC[1:9,]
ID      CNDIST1    CNDIST2
C1       0,0,136,1       0,0,4,2
C2       0,0,141,1       0,0,4,1
C3         6,8,126         0,0,4
C4        6,11,125         0,0,6
C5 0,0,141,0,0,0,0 0,0,3,0,1,0,1
C6      0,0,139,0,0     0,0,3,1,1
C7        0,0,141,0       0,0,4,2
C8        0,0,141,0       0,0,4,2
C9         31,44,61         2,2,2
```

The same dataframe using dput():

```
dput(CNC[1:9,])
structure(list(ID = structure(1:9, .Label = c("C1", 
"C2", "C3", "C4", 
"C5", "C6", "C7", 
"C8", "C9"), class = "factor"), 
CNDIST1 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
6L), .Label = c("0,0,136,1", "0,0,139,0,0", "0,0,141,0", 
"0,0,141,0,0,0,0", "0,0,141,1", "31,44,61", "6,11,125", "6,8,126"
), class = "factor"), CNDIST2 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("0,0,3,0,1,0,1", "0,0,3,1,1", 
"0,0,4", "0,0,4,1", "0,0,4,2", "0,0,6", "2,2,2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"CNDIST1", "CNDIST2"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

And i am using the below Rcode to do chisq.test. The values in column3  form the probablities vector 'p' of the same length of numeric vector 'x' from column2

```
read.table("report.dat2",header=T,sep="\t")->CNC
chi.pval=vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(CNC)){
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(CNC$CNDIST1[i]),",")))->x
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(CNC$CNDIST2[i]),",")))->p
chi.pval[i]<-chisq.test(x,p+0.001,rescale.p=T)$p.value  ###add 0.001 to 'p' vector to remove '0'
}
CNC1<-cbind(CNC,chi.pval)
write.table(CNC1,'chi.test.txt',sep='\t',quote=F,row.names=F)
```

The code return the error:

```
Error in chisq.test(x, p + 0.001, rescale.p = T) : 
'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In chisq.test(x, p + 0.001, rescale.p = T) :
Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The code shows the error while doing chisq.test on some rows and exits. However it does the test for some rows of the dataframe. Does anyone offer a clue to find out what's happening to fix this?

dput(CNC[1:9,])) is missing some values in DIST1 and DIST2. Looks like something wierd is happening with duplicate values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: modified the question based on the link!!